# Adding custom class based on Bootstrap CSS 2.3.2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I've included Bootstrap CSS, and now want to add a custom `class` in my own CSS file.

It is simply an exact copy of `.btn-success` with modified colors and `class` name only:

```
.btn-mine {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #ff8d53;
    border-color: #ef8343;
}
.btn-mine:hover,
.btn-mine:focus,
.btn-mine:active,
.btn-mine.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-mine {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #ea793e;
    border-color: #dc5930;
}
.btn-mine:active,
.btn-mine.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-mine {
    background-image: none;
}
.btn-mine.disabled,
.btn-mine[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-mine,
.btn-mine.disabled:hover,
.btn-mine[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-mine:hover,
.btn-mine.disabled:focus,
.btn-mine[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-mine:focus,
.btn-mine.disabled:active,
.btn-mine[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-mine:active,
.btn-mine.disabled.active,
.btn-mine[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-mine.active {
    background-color: #ff8d53;
    border-color: #ff6314;
}
.btn-mine .caret {
    border-top-color: #fff;
}
.dropup .btn-mine .caret {
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/qG2n6/.

I know there are many 3rd-party Bootstrap button makers which can create buttons of any colors.

**But I am more interested in knowing why my approach above does not work**.

I copy all the styles that contains `.btn-success` in the original Bootstrap CSS, and only modify the colors and the `class` name, and I expected it to work.

**What am I missing here?**

Comment: Is the CSS file loaded into the web-page? Are you using the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.btn-success` contains

```
.btn-success {
background-color: #5BB75B;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #62C462, #51A351);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
color: #FFFFFF;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
```

While your class contains just some border and background color

Comment: searching for `.btn-success` in this file: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css, I don't see any of the above for the class.

Comment: It is in bootstrap-theme.css https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css
Accept the answer if it helped. :)

Comment: Ah! what's the relationship between `bootstrap-theme.css` and `bootstrap.css`? Are they merged into one file for the actual Bootstrap css in release?

Comment: They've taken out all theme related from main css file to bootstrap-theme.css  So that you can easily customize the color related stuffs.
This happened when they updated to v3 of bootstrap.

Comment: that explains it all! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to override the background-image as well. That is where the slight gradient of the buttons in Bootstrap 2.3.2 comes from. See here:

```
.btn-mine {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #ff8d53;
    border-color: #ef8343;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qG2n6/1/

If you add background-image: none;, add the IE filter and alter the text shadow you will get your button. However, if you want a gradient to match the style of your version of Bootstrap you will need you own CSS gradient. You can use this tool to make one of your own:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Which might look something like this:

```
.btn-mine {
    color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #dc5930;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    background: #ff8d53;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ff8d53 0%, #ff732d 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff8d53), color-stop(100%,#ff732d));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ff8d53 0%,#ff732d 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ff8d53 0%,#ff732d 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ff8d53 0%,#ff732d 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ff8d53 0%,#ff732d 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff8d53', endColorstr='#ff732d',GradientType=0 );
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qG2n6/3/

Comment: i searched for `.btn-success` in this file: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css, and I didn't see `background`, `filter`, etc defined for the class, are they defined somewhere else?

Comment: @MLister that is version 3.0.0 you are linking to. They went with a more flat, and customizable, design. If you look through 2.3.2 you will find it.